# Caching Application Block

Tags: c#, .net

I'm adding Microsoft Caching application block to a c# project.
Is there anyway to set the maximum memory usage the application block will use.

I know I can set `maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavengings` in cache etc... However I don't know in advance what sort of size each item will be.

Therefore I'd like to say max memory usage = 300mb or something rather than number of items.

The application is a C# WPF application running on a PC with a small memory installation (2GB) or less. I want to cache data in memory, but obviously I need to ensure the cache doesn't start eating up that 2GB competely.

Comment: [In 2011, they said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753(v=pandp.50).aspx): _"Caching Application Block functionality is built into .NET Framework 4.0; therefore the Enterprise Library Caching Application Block will be deprecated in releases after 5.0. You should consider using the .NET 4.0 System.Runtime.Caching classes instead of the Caching Application Block in future development."_ -> [`System.Runtime.Caching`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Good question. I would like to hear the answer.

Comment: If you do go down the System.Runtime.Caching route just set CacheMemoryLimit on the memory cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx, you can also specify a limit in terms of % of physical memory.

Comment: @JamesGaunt to you want to submit your comment as the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this can't be done with the caching application block.
However as CodeCaster pointed out I should use the System.Runtime.Caching clases instead anyway.

I've replaced that and set the Limit as James Gaunt pointed out.

Below is the XML for the app.config to do it.

```
  <system.runtime.caching>
    <memoryCache>
      <namedCaches>
        <add name="Default"
             cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="200"
             physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="20"
             pollingInterval="00:05:01" />
      </namedCaches>
    </memoryCache>
  </system.runtime.caching>
```